# Using a PHP variable in an RLIKE regex

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I'd like to search the Categories table for the `$term` passed in.
The code below doesn't work.

```
$term= ($_POST['term']);

"SELECT *
FROM Categories
WHERE Cat4 RLIKE  '[[:<:]]$term[[:>:]]'
";
```

I've tried `"[[:<:]]$term[[:>:]]"` but that doesn't work either. 
Is there a way to use a variable in the `RLIKE` regex?

Comment: Beware of "SQL injection".

Comment: Conside using a `FULLTEXT` index -- _much_ faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `$term` within `{}`.

```
$term= ($_POST['term']);

$query="SELECT * FROM Categories WHERE Cat4 RLIKE  '[[:<:]]{$term}[[:>:]]'";
```

Comment: Thanks.  That worked.  I wouldn't have known that from reading the documentation you pointed to, though. That documentation is about escaping PHP strings with backslashes and there are no backslashes in my example.

Comment: @Steve: Glad it worked. I think I pointed to wrong documentation in haste. I will remove it.

Comment: Ok, but if you have documentation on it, or can explain why it worked, I'd be very interested.

Comment: Without the braces _PHP_ thinks the brackets are for fetching from an array called `$term`.

Comment: @RickJames: Is there any documentation ? Because I sort of assumed that it will work based on some prior knowledge.

Comment: Try this:  `$x = array('foo'); echo "$x[0]";`  (Sorry I don't know where to look in the PHP docs, and it may not seem very relevant.)